# Django - Why pictures are not served

Tags: python, django, static, media

Here is my project structure:

[image]

I need to upload a picture (via the admin interface ) before loading it in the template.

I found many posts about the same probleme and I followed the same steps described in answers:

My settings.py:

```py
 DEBUG = True
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
```

My urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My models.py:

```py
class Image_blog(models.Model):
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'blog')
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry,related_name='images')
    ...
```

Finally, in the template:

```html
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <a href="blog-post.html">
                        {% for img in entry.images.all %}
                            <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="{{ img.pic.url }}" alt="">
                        {% endfor %}
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

The problem that I got this error:

```
 GET http://localhost:8000/media/blog/django.png 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Despite that the picture is there:

[image]

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

**Edit**
In case it can help:

- I am using django 1.8

Comment: try to use: src="{{ img.pic }}"

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis That won't work

Comment: Is `DEBUG = True`? `static()` is a no-op when not in debug mode. Side note: `default=...` looks wrong to me, the uploaded file paths are stored relative to the media root (so that you can move it later), so  the absolute path isn't going to cut it.

Comment: @dhke,`DEBUG=True` and the `default=` is useless here becaus, the picture is uploaded.

Comment: Make sure you added `static()` to the root urls.py, and not a different one.

Comment: @Alasdair!! That worked! Can you please put your answer to accept it? Thank you man :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have added this line to your **root** url config.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

If you have, for example,

```
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

and you add `static()` there, then Django would add a url pattern to serve the media files at `/blog/^media/`. That won't even make the files available at `/blog/media/`, because of the `^`.